# How do we implement a logger for server side part in remix framework, what would be the best approach?

Tags: node.js, logging, remix

I want to implement logging functionality for an application which is using remix framework.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in Remix can be done like in any Node server. A barebone approach is to use `console.log`. Otherwise, other logging libraries are available. For example https://github.com/pinojs/pino